# How do you give users in AWS user-pools access to other aws services

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito

I have my user pool and federated pools linked.

I am able to sign up and verify a user however it does not register on the console in the user federated identity pool.  It only comes up as unauthenticated.

What do I need to do in order to have my users stop showing up as unauthorized users and have them show up as users in my userpool?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you both have unauthenticated identities enabled and are not correctly setting the User Pools token before communicating with Cognito after authenticating. Cognito Federated Identities thinks you haven't given a token, which is why you're seeing only unauthenticated ids. Give [this docs page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-integrating-user-pools-with-identity-pools.html) a read, the short version is the logins need to be set like this:

```
logins.put("cognito-idp.<region>.amazonaws.com/<YOUR_USER_POOL_ID>", session.getIdToken().getJWTToken());
```